# torch cuda not able to identify gpu on aws g4dn.xlarge

Tags: pytorch, generative-models, cuda

I have created an `EC2` instance with `GPU`  `g4dn.xlarge` and launched it. I want to run some code from command line and this code is `pytorch` based. While `pycuda` is able to identify the `GPUs` the `pytorch` is not able to identify it.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import torch
cuda.init()
num_gpus = cuda.Device.count()
print(f"Number of GPUs: {num_gpus}")
print("is torch cuda avaialable",torch.cuda.is_available())
print("torch cuda count",torch.cuda.device_count())
```

the output for the above code will be

```
Number of GPUs: 1
is torch cuda avaialable False
torch cuda count 0
```

Here are the `pytorch` and `cuda` version I am using

```
pytorch                   2.0.1           cpu_py310h07ccb54_0
cudatoolkit               11.7.0              h254b3b0_10    nvidia
pycuda                    2021.1          py310h06b8198_3    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is you have the cpu version of pytorch installed instead of the gpu version. If you go to the pytorch home page: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ you can use the configuration table to install the cuda 11 or cuda 12 version of pytorch and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have made use of the get started locally installation command locally on on whole fresh conda environment and I am still getting the error. `conda install pytorch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia`. This command additionally had torchaudio which I removed from the `install` command as the package was not found during `conda install`

Comment: hmm, is it possibly a mismatch between pytorch version and Cuda version? Do you need pytorch-cuda 11.7 or can you upgrade to the latest version (12.1 I believe)? Same question for the drivers - do you have the latest Nvidia drivers for pytorch for your card and Cuda version?

Comment: this is solved as I had to install GPU CUDA and also match the cuda and nvidia driver version for compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Use `nvidia-smi` to troubleshoot. Depending on what it says, you need to get and install the nvidia cuda driver. If you've upgraded your kernel (or had it automatically applied) you need to reinstall the cuda driver.

If `nvidia-smi` shows correct GPU data, then something is wrong with pytorch install.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nvidia-smi` to match the correct `nvidia driver` that can work with your desired `cuda toolkit`

Make sure to install `GPU` version of the `cuda toolkit`. https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ should be able to help you choose your desired version.